# Why does this Worksheet_change loop crash if row insert causes number of rows > 100?

Tags: vba, excel

The purpose of the below code is to number rows 6 to rowCount from 1 to rowCount in numerical order in col B. When the user inserts a row, the numbers automatically adjust. For example, if the user inserts a new row between rows 6 and 7, the new row is numbered 7 in col B, the previous row 7 is renumbered 8, and the remaining rows are renumbered 9 to rowCount. This works fine until rowCount >= 100. Then when the user inserts a new row, the program crashes. Why? What's so special about 100 and above? Is there a better method for auto re-renumbering the rows when the user inserts a new row?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

Dim i As Long, rowCount As Long

rowCount = UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 6 To rowCount
    If Me.Cells(i, 2) <> i - 5 Then
        Me.Cells(i, 2) = i - 5
    End If
Next
```

Comment: It does not necessarily crash. I just tested it (with more than 300 lines ...) and it works fine for me (Excel 2003 with compatibility pack on Windows XP).

Comment: Where did you insert the new row? Please try inserting a new row between 6 and 7.

Comment: You need to use `Application.EnableEvents = False`. If you search for that and Worksheet_Change, you'll get explanations of why.

Comment: It does not seem to matter where I insert the lines: between 6 and 7, before line 6 or after line 7 ... Everything behaves as it should. Maybe you have another SUB somewhere hidden in your project that gets triggered by the change and the error is somewhere hidden inside that SUB?

Comment: @DougGlancy Is right: whenever the `If` condition is satisfied the `Worksheet_change` event fires again and again.. So the subroutine repeats itself.

Comment: @DougGlancy and loannis, you are quite right. Added the Application.EnableEvents = False, which cleared it right up. Much obliged

Comment: Agree with @DougGlancy! See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640

Comment: Good that the problems does not require fixing but it would be good to know what caused the problem. I see that the script would create many unnecessary loops but it does not appear to be an infinite loop. At worst, around 5,000 loops. Why would that cause a crash?

Comment: It would be infinite, actually as the `Change` event keeps creating a new one. Also, be aware that you shouldn't use SO's answer feature to ask questions. I'm going to flag this for closure.

Comment: Doug Glancy provided the correct answer in his comments: Need to use Application.EnableEvents = False. You say there are unnecessary loops. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here,

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim i As Long
For i = 6 To UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If Me.Cells(i, 2) <> i - 5 Then Me.Cells(i, 2) = i - 5
    End If
Next
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
'[![screenshot][1]][2]
```

[image: screenshot]